# Grails 3.2.8 not able to get springSecurityService.currentUser in controller

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails3

I'm unable to get springSecurityService.currentUser from a controller in Grails 3.2.8.

Please note that Grails 3.2.8 made some performance improvements not in previous versions that seem to be breaking Spring Security Core. As per [Grails 3.2.8 dependency injection in domain classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059313/grails-3-2-8-dependency-injection-in-domain-classes/43072551#43072551), I set grails.gorm.autowire = true, which fixed that incompatibility.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Grails 3.2.8 web app with Spring Security 3.1.1 using Roles and Groups.
2. In application.yml, set grails.gorm.autowire = true
3. In Bootstrap:

   ```
   def init = { servletContext ->
       User user = new User(username: 'foo', password:'foo').save(flush: true)
       Role role = new Role(authority: 'SomeRole').save(flush: true)
       RoleGroup roleGroup = new RoleGroup(name: 'SomeRole').save(flush: true)
       RoleGroupRole.create(roleGroup, role)
       UserRoleGroup.create(user, roleGroup)
   }
   ```
4. Create a controller TestController:

   ```
   @Secured(['SomeRole'])
   class TestController {
       def springSecurityService

       def index() {
           println "springSecurityService==null? ${(springSecurityService==null).toString()}"
           println "SecurityContextHolder.context==null? ${(SecurityContextHolder.context==null).toString()}"
           println "SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication==null? ${(SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication==null).toString()}"
           println "springSecurityService.principal==null? ${(springSecurityService.principal==null).toString()}"
           println "springSecurityService.currentUser==null? ${(springSecurityService.currentUser==null).toString()}"

           render "1" //Render something so we don't get an exception.
       }
   }
   ```
5. Start up the server and go to /test. The output is:

   ```
   springSecurityService==null? false
   SecurityContextHolder.context==null? false
   SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication==null? true
   springSecurityService.principal==null? true
   springSecurityService.currentUser==null? true`
   ```

Is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SecurityContextHolder.context` is not null (it should never be null) but 
`SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication` is null, then this is probably not a Grails or a plugin issue - you're not authenticated. So there's no principal to get the cached user id from (i.e. `springSecurityService.principal` is null as your output shows) and there's no way to retrieve the current User instance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Since version 3.2.8 there is this default setting in application.yml: grails.gorm.autowire=false. You have to set it to true then the services autowire as always.